# How To make Some Text In a whatsapp message as link

Tags: php, wordpress, api, hyperlink, whatsapp

I want to make a particular text as link in whatsapp text so that it can be copied rather then coping full message i just want that particular text to get copied as in the screenshot : https://prnt.sc/taago5 you can see that its blue in color that means its like a link when long pressed it gets copied.
similarly i want the text in red box as link so that it can be copied : https://prnt.sc/taahd4

Comment: We are not code writing service, Tell us what you have done so far!

Comment: How are you connecting to WhatsApp? API call?

Comment: Yes i am using API

Comment: Also don't forget to accept a given answer if it answers your question.

Comment: When asking questions it's always best to include any textual content as formatted text in your question description. If it makes sense to have a picture (because it's a picture and not text or code, ...) then embed it into your question – avoid linking to some off-site resource (which might disappear sometime).

Answer (score 8):

You simply *can not* make just any arbitrary text you want, become a link. There is no mechanism or syntax provided to achieve this.

WhatsApp parses the message content, and replaces parts that match certain patterns with links automatically - for example HTTP/HTTPS URLs.

What your first screenshot shows, `544-497-293`, gets recognized as a (potential) *phone number* here, and *that* is why it gets transformed into a link automatically.

But you won’t be able to force this in any way, for the arbitrary format you have in your second screenshot.